# run a bash script located in public folder github actions

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have this script `createmap.sh` in the `public/scripts` folder. I need to run it on master deployment
the code in yaml file is

```
name: create-map
on: push

run: .public/script.sh
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
shell: bash
```

it is a simple script that is supposed to create a sitemap and ping google

```
# yarn sitemap
$ cd public
$ rm -rf sitemap
$ mkdir sitemap
$ cd ..
$ cd scripts
$ node ./sitemap-posts.js
$ node ./compress-map.js
$ node ./create-one-map.js

$ curl http://google.com/ping?sitemap=https://website.com/sitemap.xml
```

My folder structure is `rootdirectory/scripts` and `rootdirectory/public`

When I deploy the scripts are not run and I don't know where the problem is

Comment: Do you have any error on console? If yes, then include that in the post and also show us the contents of directories scripts and public with `ls -l`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to add permission for execution:

```yaml
jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Run script file
      run: |
         chmod +x ./public/scripts/test.sh
         ./public/scripts/test.sh
      shell: bash
```

Comment: It is up to you. There is no restriction here. You only need to pay attention to refer properly to them. Do it in a place where it is convenient for you.

Comment: I am a beginner in this. actually this is the only deployment in Actions I will be doing. Can you modify it a bit to include installing npm modules. I thought the packages in package.json file would be used

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej : What's the point in setting the x-bit before every execution? It should be sufficient to set it once manually. An alternative would be to use `bash ./public/scripts/test.sh` as run-command. In this case, the x-bit does not matter.

Comment: The point is to have file executable. There are various way of getting this. Your alternative also should work. However, just `run: ./public/scripts/test.sh` doesnt work.

Comment: Can you add the line where say I need to install an npm module eg "prettier". Where should that line be. I'll appreciate it a lot

Comment: Problem is that I am not exactly sure what do you want to achieve. Is above script complete?

Comment: Yes it is. I'll create another question

Comment: Do check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625629/install-npm-modules-in-github-actions

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having to make it executable on every iteration if you update the index in git as follows:

`git update-index --chmod=+x  ./.github/script.sh`

You can find a more detailed explanation @ https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index.