# install npm modules in github actions

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have this script that is supposed to create a sitemap on each master deployment

```
name: create-map
on: push

jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '12'
        check-latest: true
    - name: Run script file
      run: |
      
         chmod +x ./scripts/createmap.sh
         ./scripts/createmap.sh
      shell: bash
```

`createmap.sh` script looks like

```
cd public
rm -rf sitemap
mkdir sitemap
cd ..
cd scripts
node ./sitemap-posts.js
node ./compress-map.js
node ./create-one-map.js

curl http://google.com/ping?sitemap=https://website.com/sitemap.xml
```

The three scripts above `eg. sitemap-posts` are located in the root folder of my website in `scripts` folder. They have modules at the top of each file like

```
const fs = require("fs");
const globby = require("globby");
const prettier = require("prettier");
const firebase = require("firebase");
```

When a deployment is done an error occurs `Error: Cannot find module 'prettier'` and  `Error: Cannot find module 'globby'`. I am fairly new to this and i thought these modules would be fetched from my website `package.json` file.

How do I fix these errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't run `npm install` before executing the scripts in `createmap.sh`.

Please also note that the `node_modules` directory have to be a sibling of sitemap-posts.js, compress-map.js and create-one-map.js